# UISplitViewController - presenting modal view controller over the detailed view controller in landscape problem

Tags: ipad, modal-dialog, uisplitviewcontroller

When I try to show some view in modal mode over the detailed view of the UISPlitViewController in landscape mode by this code:

```
UIViewController *controller = ....
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self.detailedViewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

...after dismissing it, detailed view is moved  to the left and hides behind master view controller. It looks like origin of the detailed view shifts to the origin of the master view (menu in my case)?
Why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show the modal view over your SplitViewController, not over the detail.

Comment: Hi @Sulthan, I have presented one ModalView using splitViewController, now I want to present another modalView , immediately after dismissing this , using splitviewController, I tried it but its crashing.check this out http://pastebin.com/atWn5r4C